# How to upload a one terabyte file to Amazon S3 via webapp?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

I would like to know how to upload large files to amazon S3 (> 1 terabyte)

Ideally the web-app upload mechanism should have:

1. Real time progress bar
2. Upload Speed stats
3. Pause / Resume Support
4. Upload directly from computer to amazon S3
5. Memory efficient, so that the large file can be sent via the web browser.

I have tried *Uploadify S3* via *Django*. Although it looks like it can not handle large files very well.

Does anyone know about an existing demo app on Github or documentation using any of the following languages?

- Rails
- Django
- PHP
- Java

Recently, also I have goggled about the **Knox S3 library** and *nodejs*, although I haven't found a demo app for uploading.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job.  This is exactly what FTP was designed for.  HTTP... not so much.

Comment: That's a good point. And it makes sense. Although the client still wants this via a web application.

Comment: Java app-based FTP client that can be embedded in a website?

Comment: Thanks! Probably that is the most reliable solution. I have been looking for a free java applet of java app that can emulate an FTP site for S3.

Answer (score 2):

try resumable.js , it's a javascript library that supports chunking, but only in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Also you might want to try https://github.com/Boxee/node-s3-resumable-upload
It allows to start uploading like a regular client, and then if something goes wrong, resume the upload, so that most clients are supported, and resuming is an "unobtrusive enhancement"